# Is it possible to extend go struct constructors?

Tags: go

given

```
type Rectangle struct {
    h, w int
}

func (rec *Rectangle) area() int {
    return rec.w * rec.h
}
```

Can you define a `Square` struct using Rectangle, so I can make use of area method? It is absolutely fine if it is not possible. I won't judge the language or cry or get upset. I am just learning the golang.

Comment: Go doesn't have constructors, do you mean something like this?: https://play.golang.org/p/ra3Wl0I0kM

Comment: possible syntax I can __imagine__  is  `Square{2}` rather than  `Square{Rectangle{2,2}}` .

Comment: I'm not sure how you imagine that would work, even if there were some notion of inheritance in Go. `Square{2}` is just a literal value, it doesn't _do_ anything.

Comment: I meant a struct Square definition that will me define a Square in this form `Square{2}`. This is not possible as I understand, which is fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go isn't classically object-oriented, so it doesn't have inheritence. It also doesn't have constructors.  What it does have is embedding.  Thus this is possible:

```
type Rectangle struct {
    h, w int
}

func (rec *Rectangle) area() int {
    return rec.w * rec.h
}

type Square struct {
    Rectangle
}
```

The main limitation here is that there's no way for the `area()` method to access fields that only exist in `Square`.

Answer (score 2):

I came to know that the expected way to achieve this behaviour is to write ordinary functions. see `MakeSquare`

```
type Rectangle struct {
    h, w int
}

func (rec *Rectangle) area() int {
    return rec.w * rec.h
}

type Square struct {
    Rectangle
}

func MakeSquare(x int) (sq Square) {
    sq.h = x
    sq.w = x
    return
}

func Test_square(t *testing.T) {
    sq := MakeSquare(3)
    assert.Equal(t, 9, sq.area())
}
```